# Linux install on HP Thin client issues and

Tags: linux, boot, debian, sd-card

TLDR: I want to install Linux on a HP thin client, but no matter what I do I get the blinking cursor in the top left.

---

*Sorry if this is not a question for "superuser" - happy to move if it belongs elsewhere*

**Background**

I'm a web developer who is confident on the command line. Once the command line is there, I am content. I prefer a flavour of Debian. I've set up several Raspberry Pi's in my time and use Linux at work on a daily basis.

**Objective**

I currently have a Pi as my home "hub". Running scripts and generally helping out. It's not powerful enough for the next step for me which is to run Plex (which is currently running on my NAS) and to be a VPN gateway for devices in my home.

I've picked up a HP T5740 to handle this. I've upgraded the RAM to 4GB. It has an Intel Atom 1.6ghz processor

**Why I need help**

The computer had 2gb of flash storage as it's "hard drive" which I didn't consider enough for me. I did some googling and found using USB SD card reader was the cheapest, best solution for me at the moment. The computer does have SATA connector, so my plan was to install on an SD card then eventually pick up a STATA -> SD card connector to increase the speed. So I'm currently installing Linux on a16gb SDHC card.

I've attempted to install Debian 9  two times now and both times have resulted in a "successful installation". Upon reboot, I just get the blinking cursor in the top right - which I understand to be an error.

To install, I have downloaded the `bootloader.img` onto a USB stick and the ISO onto a second. During installation, the computer is attached to the network to download the further packages required. This all seems to work fine.

**Question time**

There are a few questions here - some specific to the issue above, others general questions that I have. Any answers to any of them would be hugely appreciated.

1. Is Debian 9 the best version of Linux to install?
2. Is it wise to install onto an SD card?
3. What does the blinking cursor actually mean? Is there any way to work out what is erroring?
4. Is there a better way to install Debian? With Raspbian I flash the actual OS onto the SD card and just boot it up. Is there a way to do do this with Debian?
5. What makes Raspian specific to Raspberry Pis - is it to do with the processor & hardware?

Thank you, thank you, thank you.

Comment: Is the card reader USB? If so, have you verified it's actually bootable on another computer? Not all external card readers are bootable, and not all bootable external card readers are compatible with all BIOSes.

Comment: @Larssend interesting. It appears in the BIOS as a bootable option when I got into that option, so I assume yes?

Comment: You should actually try to boot from it on another computer. Sometimes the embedded firmware contains inadvertent bugs or is simply incomplete.

Answer (score 0):

For your Answers :-

1. I Think Debian 9 would be a very nice choice to install.
2. As for the SD card installation I would never recommend anyone for
   installing an OS on a SD card (Even a SDHC card) but it has its own advantages.
3. As for the blinking cursor, are you sure you install Debian on the right SD card and configured the bootloader to boot from it, **and set the SD card in boot priority in BIOS.**
4. You can make a live usb out of the SD card either by using [LiLi](https://www.linuxliveusb.com/) or following the guide [here](https://wiki.debian.org/DebianEeePC/HowTo/InstallOnSDcardOrUsbStick).
5. Raspbian is not that specific to just Raspberry pi but it is configured and tweaked to run on low-end hardware and and support Raspi's booting procedures.(It is in reality a fork of Debian 8.)

Comment: Thank you so much. Definitely selected the right SD card. In my situation, what would you recommend for an installation source? I did the guided partioning and didn't change any settings and it's definitely boot first in BIOS

Answer (score 0):

1. You can install to this thin client Debian 9 without problems. I tried this but on ssd disk which was connected to sata port.
2. I prefer SSD disk or mSata with msata to sata converter adapter from aliexpress

Comment: I'm not sure this answers the question. Could you elaborate on what you're saying?

Answer (score 0):

As a follow up to this, I decided to utilise a hard drive (the client had the connector to allow me to do this) and purchased a cheap SSD for all my purposes!

Answer (score 0):

My HP t5740 (3GB RAM):
2GB Flash: WinXP/SP2, with it own MBR on the Flash-drive, but for reasons of space without (dot).Net/Framework. It took me some puzzling to find and download the required Intel and Realtek-drivers. Now WinXP works fine.
Additional SD-card or USB2.0 or USB3.0: Linux. Lubuntu fits on 8GB, Mint needs more. I use a 32GB USB3.0-drive.

Of decisive importance is the Read/Write-speed of your SD resp. USB-drive. Check your speed with Linux Disks, sits inside every Linux distro. For me both SD and USB3.0 work fine.

Important when installing Linux:
1/ Check your BIOS boot sequence. First boot must be USB, this is also the BIOS-default setting.
2/ Start your live Linux USB (or external CD/DVD). Your live Linux must be up and running before you insert your target SD/USB-drive.
3/ Partition your target SD/USB and do not forget to install the Linux bootloader on the target SD/USB. If you accept the default value, Linux will install its bootloader on the flash drive and you may get lost.

If everything goes well, you will have two boot options:

1/ Via BIOS => Flash => Windows XP starting from its own MBR (Windows doesn't see Linux at all)
2/ Via BIOS/Default: Linux starts it own bootloader and offers you a dual boot menu: Linux and Windows. I choose this as my default setting.

Good Linucks!

Answer (score -1):

The T5740 is sometimes touchy with bootloaders. I think the internal BIOS does not fully use the standard boot procedure on internal drives.
I think the primary partition MUST be FAT (with syslinux) or NTFS partition.

I couldn't manage to install Linux or Android X86 boot from internal "SSD", but it works from a USB stick.
I finally had to use this option: having an USB key in on of the USB slots than are "embedded".